# Exit JS Function out of jquery each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm using a jquery $.each function to do some things in a table. If some value in this table is empty, I want to stop the complete function.
"return false;" is only breaking the each loop, but not the complete function.
How can I do this?

```
function readFields(){
    $('#tbl_units').each(function(key, value){
        if($(value).val() === undefined){
           return false; //This one will only break the .each, but not the complete readFields-function. But I want to completely exit the readFields function
        }
        //Some other stuff todo
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Your `each()` loop is completely redundant as you're selecting an id, and there should only ever be a single `#tbl_units` element in the DOM. If you've got more than one, that's a problem you need to correct.

Comment: and if you do need lots oof elements, just use a traditional `for` loop

Comment: *only breaking the each loop, but not the complete function* - why would it?  If you move your anon-function/callback to a named function `function readFieds() { $("..").each(myfunction); } function myfunction() { return false; }` you wouldn't expect the `return` from `myfunction()` to break out of `readFields`.

Comment: To do this, you need something in the outer function to be set by something in the inner function, eg `var failed = false; $(..).each((i,e) => { if ($(e).val() == undefined) failed=true; }); if (failed) return;`

Comment: Having said that you *should* probably do this some other way, eg with `.filter`  `if ($("...").filter((i, e) => $(e).val() === undefined).length > 0) return;`